# AngularJS: [$injector:strictdi] error when loading directives for ngAutocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to do an autocomplete textbox using AngularJS, I've added `ngAutocomplete` in angular module, but unable to load the directive

Angular Code:

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('npi', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngAutocomplete','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$compileProvider', '$routeProvider',function($compileProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $compileProvider.commentDirectivesEnabled(false);
    //$compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
    //$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
    $routeProvider
      when("/part/:part_id", {
          templateUrl : "/html/part_detail.html",
         controller : "partDetail"
       })
   }]);
```

part_details.js

```
"use strict";
app.controller("partDetail", [
        '$scope',
        '$http',
        '$log',
        '$window',
        '$routeParams',
        function($scope, $http, $log, $window, $routeParams) {
            $scope.$parent.title = "Part Detail";
            $scope.$parent.selectpartAttribute = "";
            $scope.sample = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'];
            } ]);
```

part_detail.html

```
<input auto-complete ui-items="sample" ng-model="selectpartAttribute.attribute_group" />
<input type="text" ng-model="selectpartAttribute.attribute_name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="selectpartAttribute.attribute_value" />
```

auto_complete.js

```
"use strict";
app.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
      source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
      select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger('input');
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Now directive does not load when `input` clicked

Error
[image]
*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Make sure you are referencing `ngAutocomplete.js` (or the file that contains that module) in your `<script>` imports, and make sure that that reference comes before your code where you load your own module. It might be worth sharing the order of your `<script>` imports in the question.

Comment: @MatthewCawley Now i understood, i corrected the mistake, but now autocomplete can't work

Comment: Do you mean it "_can't_ work", or it "(still) _doesn't_ work"? You need to provide more information as to what problem you're facing.

Comment: @MatthewCawley editted the question, pls check it

Comment: Okay, and if you press F12 is there an error on the console? I'd still include the `<script src="...">` tag imports in the question, you've provided the contents of some of those files but not the order in which they're imported, it's an obvious place to start i.e. "Are all dependencies being loaded upfront, and in the correct order?"

Comment: thanks, i changed the order, now it's calling the directives but showing error in that, i've edited the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154484/discussion-between-matthew-cawley-and-keerthivasan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The reason that you get the `Error: $injector:strictdi` error is because you have specified strict mode without an explicit annotation for the `$timeout` service.

That's explained here: [Error: $injector:strictdi
Explicit annotation required](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi)

**Solution**

To fix this, you need to provide an **explicit annotation** when you inject the `$timeout` service into the directive like this:

```
app.directive("autoComplete", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
      source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
      select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger("input");
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

or like this:

```
app.directive("autoComplete", thisDirective);

thisDirective.$inject = ["$timeout"];

function thisDirective($timeout) {
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
      source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
      select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger("input");
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  };
}
```